# Change src and get height of that new src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a gallery with multiple images, where you can click on a small thumbnail and a bigger version of that image will open.

Once is opened if you move the cursor the image will follow you on the y-axis. Similar to https://www.zara.com/es/es/chaqueta-denim-combinada-pC33052724001.html?v1=5161517&v2=269184

**My problem**:
Everything is working fine, but when you open the image for the first time and move the cursor there's a "jump" that I'm trying to correct.
This happens because the height of ".image-zoom img" (new big image) is still not defined.

https://jsfiddle.net/z1jwyjur/2/

```
var h = 0;

function zoomTracking(event){
    h = $('.image-zoom img').height();
    var vptHeight = $(window).height();
    var y = -((h - vptHeight) / vptHeight) * event.clientY;
    $('.image-zoom img').css('top', y + "px");
    console.log(h);
}

$(function() {
    $('#grid a').click(function(e) {

      // Currently "image zoom img" src is empty. So we give him a value, the big version of the image we click.        
      var changeSrc = $(this).attr('href');
      $('.image-zoom img').attr('src', changeSrc);

      // We make appear "image zoom" 
      $('.image-zoom').fadeIn();

      // Here, the point is to get the height of the new big version of the image, and declare that height as "h". Not working... 
      h = $('.image-zoom img').height();

      zoomTracking(e);
      return false;
    });

    $('.image-zoom').mousemove(function(e) {
        zoomTracking(e);
    });

    $('.image-zoom').click(function() {
        $('.image-zoom').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

So basically what I think I need is to get the height of that new big image once the src has been changed.

---

**Notes**: On the jsfiddle the "jump" I'm trying to correct only happens the first time you click. Because the second time already knows the height. / The gallery will have different images of different aspect ratios.

---

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just wait for the image to load before "opening" the zoomed version.
At this point the height will be available and you can access it in `zoomTracking` and therefor you can get rid of the global variable `h`

```
function zoomTracking(event){
  var imageZoom = $('.image-zoom img');
  var h = imageZoom.height();
  var startPos = imageZoom.data("pointerStartPosY");
  if (startPos === undefined) {
    startPos = event.clientY;
    imageZoom.data("pointerStartPosY", startPos);
  }

  var vptHeight = $(window).height();
  var y = -((h - vptHeight) / vptHeight) * (startPos - event.clientY);
  imageZoom.css('top', y + "px");
}

$(function() {
  $('.image-zoom img').on("load", function(e) {
    $('.image-zoom').fadeIn();
  });

  $('#grid a').click(function(e) {
    $('.image-zoom img').attr('src', this.href)
                        .data("pointerStartPosY", undefined);
    return false;
  });

  $('.image-zoom').mousemove(function(e) {
    zoomTracking(e);
  });

  $('.image-zoom').click(function() {
    $('.image-zoom').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2bqfncdg/)

Comment: Thanks @andreas but the "jump" is still there.
For example, if you click on the bottom part of the small image, the big image appears, but then when you move the cursor a little bit, the image jumps.

Comment: But that's a problem with your formula for `y`

Comment: Yes, I'm at a point where I ran out of things to try... Do you think with that formula I won't get it working? It feels so close.

Comment: @Iñaki If updated my answer to fix the "jumping" because of how the value of `y` has been calculated.

Comment: the problem with this is that the behaviour is different, and depending on where you have clicked you can't see the whole image.
---
I have updated a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/z1jwyjur/1/) and I think it's close. Now it recognises the height of the new image but I need to execute "$('.image-zoom').fadeIn();" once the previous is done. Any ideas about how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make a direct reference to the element:

```
$("#my_img").height();
```

where,

```
<img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/226242/screenshots/3871814/attachments/878728/thumbnail/1976_chevrolet_blazer_fullview.jpg" id="my_img"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks @caiuby-freitas, I tried but I still have the same problem.